# Facebook SDK Login Issue

Tags: android, facebook, hash, sdk, release

I am using facebook login in my application. In fb developer settings I added developer hash key and release hash key. When i tried to login the error shows
Invalid key hash. Does not match any stored key hashs.
Then I added the shown key hash to the settings.
But it is not possible to add key hash of each devices. How to rectify this issue. I tried all the similar cases. But it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do this for each device, the keyhash that you put on the dev site is from your .keystore file which should be unique to you regardless of which device

Generate your keyhash with this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> \
        | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and the same for your debug.keystore as well. Usually the path is ~/.android/debug.keystore

You can follow full instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash

Comment: But when I use from a different device, it is showing that the app is in development mode